# Workaround for Safari iframe webkit scaling bug?

Tags: iframe, safari, webkit, scaling

There seems to be a webkit scaling bug impacting Safari for Windows (v5.1) and both Safari/Chrome for Mac.  When you create an iframe and use the CSS tag -webkit-transform with a 'scale' value less than 1 (say, 0.5), elements of the page are missing when it renders the scaled version of the page.

I've built the smallest test page I can to illustrate the issue:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>iframe webkit scale bug</title>
<style type="text/css">
iframe.preview
{
  width: 1024px;
  height: 768px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<iframe class="preview" src="http://www.google.com/"></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

As a new user to stackoverflow apparently I'm not yet allowed to attach screenshots to this post.  But I had 'em and was willing to share! :)

Imagine if you will, a screenshot from Chrome (success case, see the [I'm Feeling Lucky] button, as well as some links at the bottom... everything rendered OK at 50% scale).

Now imagine a screenshot from Safari (failure case, missing [I'm Feeling Lucky] button, no links at the bottom... many page elements missing).

This happens consistently for all sorts of pages brought into the iframe; elements just go missing.  It also seems to happen whether or not you have a wrapper div around the iframe and constrain its dimensions (that was one workaround I tried).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The Safari update yesterday (10/12/2011) fixes this bug.  Woot.